# SwipeView Javascript pause() and resume()

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm using SwipeView for a project : http://cubiq.org/swipeview
It works very well, and I wanted to know if there are something like a pause() and resume() functions to call, to stop the slider when I swipe, and then resumes it when I have finished doing stuff with touch events ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone want the same functionality, I've implemented it : https://github.com/cubiq/SwipeView/pull/57